# Forcing conic layout format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layouts

I would like to be able to export a layout in QGIS such that the resulting image is conic in shape, reflecting the CRS used.

In other words, something similar to what is show below:

[image]

Comment: New inQGIS 3.16: "New functionality was introduced which allows users to clip a map item to a shape or polygon item from their layout, allowing for non-rectangular maps within the layout." See: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#clip-layout-maps-to-shape

Comment: That is fine for a regular shape but surely not for an irregular one.

Comment: Also, I am using 3.10

Comment: Open feature request is https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47309